# Independent store to offer the existing catalog

Tags: magento2, multistore

A merchant has a Magento store products for local customers to explore new markets they want to create an independent store to offer the existing catalog with a different price and branding.
What action is required achieve this?

1. Create a new website and change the price scope in Product Attributes configuration
2. Create a new website and change the price scope to website in Store configuration
3. Create a new store view and develop a module to extend the price capacities
4. Create a new store group selecting the appropriate price scope.

What will be the Ans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Point 2 seems to be the better solution, in this way your merchant can also link the different domains and host the site as a completely new website, and can also manage the catalog and branding properly.